# Add the parent value as column in R dataset

Tags: r

I am not quite sure how to phrase the problem statement. I am trying this out in RStudio but got no clue how to get it done.

I want to add a new column that will tell me the level 1 for each of the level 2 equipments.

This is how my dataset looks like,

```
equipment <- c("cleats","whistle","Football","Bat","Pink Ball","Cricket")
level <- c(2,2,1,2,2,1)
dt <- cbind(equipment,level)
```

Comment: What's the desired output? How do you know which level 1 goes with which level 2? You have 4 level 2's and 2 level 1's.

Comment: If you give some clarity, then from what I understand, you may not need a new column at all. You can probably use filter() function in dplyr package in that case.

Comment: @MrFlick each level 1 contains all the level 2 records preceding it. So in my example I want to map Football to the first two rows and Cricket to rows 4 and 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `level` always be like `2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1`, you may try this.

```
for (i in c(dim(dt)[1]:1)){
  if (dt$level[i] == 1){
    key <- dt$equipment[i]
    
  } else {}
  if (dt$level[i] == 2){
    dt$newcol[i] <- key
  } else{
    dt$newcol[i] <- NA
  }
}

  equipment level   newcol
1    cleats     2 Football
2   whistle     2 Football
3  Football     1     <NA>
4       Bat     2  Cricket
5 Pink Ball     2  Cricket
6   Cricket     1     <NA>
```

For rows with `level == 2`, I didn't handle that yet. If some other actions needed to that rows, please let me know.

Comment: Thank you very much. This works for me after I use data.frame instead of cbind to combine the two vectors equipment and level which if figured from deschen's answer below.

Comment: @Din I'm really sorry that I forgot to paste `as.data.frame`.

Comment: you are too kind. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `fill`:

```
library(tidyverse)

equipment <- c("cleats","whistle","Football","Bat","Pink Ball","Cricket")
level <- c(2,2,1,2,2,1)
dt <- data.frame(equipment,level)

dt %>%
  mutate(level_combined = if_else(level == 1, equipment, NA_character_)) %>%
  fill(level_combined, .direction = 'up')
```

which gives:

```
  equipment level level_combined
1    cleats     2       Football
2   whistle     2       Football
3  Football     1       Football
4       Bat     2        Cricket
5 Pink Ball     2        Cricket
6   Cricket     1        Cricket
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This answer works as well. Fill seems to be a very useful function.